# Como se ejecutan scripts de sql desde C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, transact-sql

estoy intentando hacer una pequeña utilidad para ejecutar scripts seleccionandolos desde una aplicacion en C# .NET.
Estoy intentando ejecutarlos con sqlCommand pero me esta dando un problema con los tipos de datos personalizados que tenemos en la base de datos porque me dice que no los encuentra...
Os paso el codigo que estoy utilizando para ejecutar los scripts, que son ficheros ".sql"

```
public bool runSqlScriptFile(string pathStoreProceduresFile, string connectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            string script = File.ReadAllText(pathStoreProceduresFile);

            // split script on GO command
            System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> commandStrings = Regex.Split(script, @"^\s*GO\s*$",
                                     RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                foreach (string commandString in commandStrings)
                {
                    if (commandString.Trim() != "")
                    {
                        using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch (SqlException ex)
                            {
                                string spError = commandString.Length > 100 ? commandString.Substring(0, 100) + " ...\n..." : commandString;
                                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Please check the SqlServer script.\nFile: {0} \nLine: {1} \nError: {2} \nSQL Command: \n{3}", pathStoreProceduresFile, ex.LineNumber, ex.Message, spError), "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Y tambien el script que quiero que se ejecute (En este caso me crearia una funcion escalar en la base de datos):

```
    CREATE FUNCTION funPers_calcularTaraPaletizado(@IdOrden T_Id_Orden, @Bono T_Id_Bono, @IdLinea SMALLINT)
RETURNS T_Real124 AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Tara T_Real124

    SELECT @Tara = SUM(isnull(oblcu.Cantidad, 0) * isnull(a.Peso, 0))
    FROM dbo.Ordenes_Bonos_Lineas_Consumo_Ubic oblcu
    join Articulos_Almacenes_Lotes aal
    on oblcu.Lote = aal.Lote
    join articulos a
    on a.IdArticulo = aal.IdArticulo
    join Conf_Articulos ca
    on ca.IdArticulo = a.IdArticulo
    WHERE IdOrden = @IdOrden AND IdBono = @Bono AND IdLinea = @IdLinea AND isnull(ca.pers_idfase, '') <> 'S4'

    RETURN (@Tara)
END
GO
```

El problema que me esta dando al ejecutar este script es que me dice que el tipo T_Real124 no existe cuando realmente es un tipo de datos personalizado que si que está en la base de datos.

[image: Imagen del error]

A ver si me podeis decir como se podrian ejecutar esos scripts, si existe alguna forma de ejecutarlos en C#.
Muchas gracias.
Saludos.

Comment: No, perdona, lo mismo no me he explicado bien, lo único que estoy intentado hacer es ejecutar ese script para que se cree la función en la base de datos. No estoy intentando ejecutar la función, por lo que no tengo que pasar parámetros.

Comment: Hmm...pero a ver. El error que pones es del sqlserver no? Es cuando tratas de ejecutar la funcion? Si es asi..la funcion ha sido creada y no tiene nada que ver con C#. Disculpame pero no debo estar entendiendo bien tu problema...

Comment: No, lo que estoy intentando es ejecutar el script de la creacion de esa funcion. No que se ejecute esa funcion.

Comment: Lo quiero para que cuando tenga todos mis objetos de base de datos en un repositorio (tipo GIT, por ejemplo) pueda ejecutarlo (y crear esos objetos) en cualquier sitio en el que tenga clonado ese repositorio.

Comment: ...y en la tabla dbo.Ordenes_Bonos_Lineas_Consumo_Ubic existe la columna T_Real124??? revisa la línea donde declaras tara DECLARE @Tara T_Real124 como defines el tipo?

Comment: Hola ger, el tipo T_Real124 es un tipo definido por nosotros en nuestra base datos. http://prntscr.com/uqhyxf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la integración con Sql Server Management.
Agrega las referencias:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
```

código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

namespace Ejecutar_Scripts
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                
                string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=SERVIDOR_DB;Initial Catalog=BASE_DATOS;User ID=USUARIO_SQL;Password=PASSWORD";
                string script = File.ReadAllText(@"G:\pr.sql");

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

                Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);

                server = null;
                conn.Close();
                

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto Alejandro, funciona perfectamente!